# NodeJS joi returns error = null, even though error should occur

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I'm running `NodeJS` with `joi`, and are trying to validate IBM Watson IoT config object.
This is my schema:

```
const schema = {
  body: {
    config: Joi.object().keys({
      org: Joi.string().required(),
      type: Joi.string().required(),
      id: Joi.string().required(),
      domain: Joi.string().required(),
      'auth-method': Joi.string().required(),
      'auth-token': Joi.string().required()
    }).required()
  }
};
```

And this is my check:

```
Joi.validate(req.body, schema, { allowUnknown: true }, (err, value) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

This returns `null` as `error` which indicates no error, but this is even if I haven't `POST`ed any parameters to my body.

Basically I want to make sure the `body` of my `HTTP POST` contains valid JSON object like so:

```
config = {
    "org" : "organization",
    "id" : "deviceId",
    "domain": "internetofthings.ibmcloud.com",
    "type" : "deviceType",
    "auth-method" : "token",
    "auth-token" : "authToken"
};
```

Comment: You are using `err` in argument while trying to print `error`

Comment: Sorry, typo here on SO. Corrected in question.

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing Joi object to the validate function, you should be passing `schema.body.config` instead of `schema`. If body and config is supposed to be part of the validation, you should wrap them with `Joi.Object` the same way you did for all the keys inside config.